# how to transpose without getting creating headers in r?

Tags: r, dataframe

i have a dataframe which shows percent by gender

df is my dataframe

```
  sex     percent
* <chr> <dbl>
1 Men   11.7 
2 Women  7.42
```

i want to transpose the data but its getting created with some other headers.my output shows like below
on using t(df). can some one please help with this

```
            1          2         
sex      "Men"      "Women"   
percent"11.67558" " 7.41533"

i need something like below

sex      "Men"      "Women"   
percent"11.67558" " 7.41533"
```

Answer (score 1):

using colnames() function remove some other headers

```
tmp <- t(df)
colnames(tmp) <- c("", "")
tmp

#                       
# sex     "Men"   "Women"
# percent "11.70" " 7.42"
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn `sex` column to rowname and then transpose :

```
rownames(df) <- df$sex
df$sex <- NULL
t(df)

#         Men Women
#percent 11.7  7.42
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using tidyr:

```
library(tidyr)
df <- df %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(
    names_from = sex, values_from = percent
  )

df

# A tibble: 1 x 2
#     Men Women
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  11.7  7.42
```

The dataframe I used:

```
df <- data.frame(
  sex = c('Men' , 'Women'),
  percent = c(11.7L, 7.42L),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below

```
> unname(data.frame(t(df)))

sex       Men Women
percent 11.70  7.42
```

or

```
> t(setNames(unstack(rev(df)), "percent"))
         Men Women
percent 11.7  7.42
```